# Consulta sobre diseño de base de datos SQL-SERVER

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo una pequeña duda en cuanto al diseño de mi base de datos, el proyecto contiene las siguiente estructura pero no se si estará bien esa relacion entre control_cotizaciones, empresas, y paises ya que están unidas las 3, no se si eso afectará a futuro o si será una mala practica unir las tablas de esa manera, ya que ocupo a la hora de crear un control de cotizacion seleccionar el pais y que luego me tire una lista de empresas que pertenecen a ese pais y el resto de campos los obtengo por el id de la empresa seleccionada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo depende de lo que quieras representar con tus datos. Si la columna idPais representa lo mismo en la tabla Control_Cotizaciones y en la tabla Empresas deberías cambiarlo y mantenerlo solo en una de las dos tablas, ya que los campos duplicados dan bastantes problemas, por ejemplo, si una empresa cambia de de País, tendrías que cambiar el valor de la columna en las dos tablas.

Si por el contrario, las dos columnas representan información diferente, es correcto mantener ambas, porque aunque estén asociadas a la misma tabla (Paises), los datos si pueden ser diferentes en ambas columnas.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Tal como lo relatas, un `IdEmpresa` pertenece a un `idPais`, por lo tanto la relación entre `Control_Cotizaciones` y país lo tienes fijado en la relación entre ambas entidades, por lo que, atendiéndonos a las reglas de normalización, el campo `id_pais` de la tabla `Control_Cotizaciones` es redundante y también la relación entre `Control_Cotizaciones` y `Paises`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda tambien había pensado en eso pero estaba inseguro, lo que hice fue mejor ese campo idPais ponerlo como varchar y se guarde el pais que se seleccione desde una lista al usuario como lo voy a implementar